# PHP - Doctrine ORM not able to handle bit(1) types correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, types, doctrine

**UPDATE** I have filed a bug in Doctrine about this http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-400

I have the following [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) schema:

```
---
TestTable:
    columns:
        bitty: bit(1)
```

I have created the database and table for this. I then have the following PHP code:

```
$obj1 = new TestTable();
$obj1['bitty'] = b'0';
$obj1->save();

$obj2 = new TestTable();
$obj2['bitty'] = 0;
$obj2->save();
```

Clearly my attempt is to save the bit value `0` in the `bitty` column.

However after running this PHP code I get the following odd results:

```
mysql> select * from test_table;
+----+-------+
| id | bitty |
+----+-------+
|  1 |      | 
|  2 |      | 
+----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test_table where bitty = 1;
+----+-------+
| id | bitty |
+----+-------+
|  1 |      | 
|  2 |      | 
+---+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test_table where bitty = 0;                
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Those boxes are the `0x01` character, i.e. Doctrine has set the value to 1, not 0.

However I can insert 0's into that table direct from MySQL:

```
mysql> insert into test_table values (4, b'0');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test_table where bitty = 0;
+----+-------+
| id | bitty |
+----+-------+
|  4 |       | 
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What's going on? Is this a bug in Doctrine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the doctrine documentation that says Bit is a legal type.

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine does know the bit type - at least if you're using MySQL and generate Doctrine models from the existing tables.
I tried to read a few bit columns and dump the resulting objects. Basically the bit value returned is either \0 or \1, instead of 0 and 1 as I expected.